# Why weren't Hitler's actual facial features used in The Man in the High Castle?

Tags: character, realism, the-man-in-the-high-castle

I've started watching *The Man in the High Castle* (2015) and became quite impressed with the overall idea and presentation of the post-WWII alternative reality. It looked like the producers chose to use a lot of real facts/names from our history, however, they've decided not to use Hitler's real facial features and I would go as far as to say that there was no obvious resemblance to the real Hitler (IMHO). What might be the reason for such a decision, considering how easily they could've made him look recognizable? Is there some sort of moral or ethical burden?

Comment: Because he's dead?

Comment: I'm flagging this as POB because it's based on whether you think the actor looks like Hitler or not. For the record, I think he looks like a pretty close match.

Comment: I'm beginning to wonder if the OP knows what the original guy looked like... The character in the show is a dead-ringer.

Comment: @OscarBravo Pretty sure I do, considering I’ve spent a good chunk of my school years back in Eastern Europe staring at textbooks filled with photographs of dictators and war figures... Back to my point though... They show the real Kennedy and other political figures, use real names... I would natively feel like they could apply some CGI or similar to what they’ve done to Arnold in the latest terminator. But they chose to make him look unique...

Comment: @eYe I know CGI can convincingly de-age actors to make them look like their younger selves (as in *Terminator*, *Captain Marvel*, *Gemini Man* etc), but I don't know whether it can convincingly make someone look like someone else. Either way, I suspect that that level of CGI would be out of the show's budget. Even *Game of Thrones*, on a dollars-per-hour basis, had a far cheaper budget than your average blockbuster.

Comment: I think most would agree that Hitler's defining facial feature was his moustache. If someone sports a toothbrush moustache, they will inevitably be compared to either Hilter or Charlie Chaplain. It's so iconic that you really don't need much else to play the part.

Comment: @NuclearWang I absolutely disagree. Hitler has a lot of facial features, not only hairstyle and moustache. Look at the actors who have played him over the decades. Chaplin looks nothing like him, neither does Alec Guiness and a myriad of other actors who have played the role- Muser or Ganz actually do resemble his facial features somewhat.

Comment: @Polygnome I mean, that kind of makes my point - to play Hitler, you don't need to actually look anything like Hitler, you just need a little moustache. The fact that Alec Guinness and others have done just that suggests that it's "close enough" for most audiences.

Comment: @NuclearWang True, to be recognized as Hitler you probably only need to get the hairstyle right and the moustache. But the question was why they didn't choose someone who resembles Hitler more. And I'd argue that Muser actually has quite a strong resemblance to him. Hitler is not *only* his moustache and hairstyle, albeit thats probably enough to get recognized. But he does actually have a face underneath that.

Answer (score 102, accepted):

For the benefit of those like me who haven't watched the series, here's a picture of Hitler in *The Man in the High Castle*, as played by Wolf Muser:

[image]

To me, this is still recognisably Hitler, just an older, greyer Hitler. *The Man in the High Castle* takes place in 1962, when Hitler would have been 73, so it makes sense to me that he wouldn't look *exactly* like he did during World War II - he would have aged considerably since then, and indeed, he appears to have done so.

Comment: Counterpoint: you can put a side part and a toothbrush moustache on anything and it would look like Hitler.

Comment: [Literally on anything](https://www.timesofisrael.com/new-sneakers-claimed-to-resemble-adolf-hitler/)

Comment: @ChrisL.Barnes True, but Muser still resembles Hitler more than some others who have portrayed him, like Alec Guiness (very little resemblance), Anthony Hopkins (very little resemblance) or Charlie Chaplin, Michael Sheard, Ian McKellen, Noah Taylor, Robert Carlyle (no resemblance whatsoever). I think Muser is quite a good choice, facially. Like with Bruno Ganz, you can clearly see the resemblance, imho.

Comment: @infinitezero [Indeed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cats_That_Look_Like_Hitler)

Comment: @Polygnome Wow, that list makes me want a fake Hitler photo gallery, or maybe a "spot the real Hitler" quiz :)

Comment: @ChrisL.Barnes: There's a difference between looking like Hitler and wanting to look like hitler. I look nothing like the man, and if I were to don the haircut and mustache, I still wouldn't look like him, but you would infer that I am trying to make myself look like him regardless. Those are different things. The man in this picture believably looks like Hitler (and oddly even more like Bruno Ganz, the actor who played Hitler in Downfall/Der Untergang, from the well known video meme).

Comment: @infinitezero Or a house: https://images.app.goo.gl/4PriWaJyuqDxsmuSA

Comment: @F1Krazy - with that hair, he reminds me very much of someone else!

Comment: I *really* hope we don't start seeing CAPTCHAs with "select all the items that look like Hitler".

Comment: @acc The implications about why Google would be doing that are interesting though...

Comment: @Acccumulation I could imagine what a shitstorm that would give, especially if the CAPTCHA were to include people that live right now and profess politics with fascist undertones.

Comment: Not the kind of discussion I intended to bring in... oh well